# How to group/categorize multiple datatables?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a series of datatables which are populated at run time and I would like a way to categorize and index them so that I can do a lookup to a specific datatable. I was thinking of having a datatable of datatables, ie whose rows contain a reference to a datatable. Is there a better way you guys can think of to design this? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just to use IDictionary<TKey, TValue>? Keep it simple

Answer (score 2):

You can store the datatables in a `Dictionary`

```
var allDataTables = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();
if (allDataTables.Contains("DataTableA"))
{
   var dataTableA = allDataTables["DataTableA"];
   //work with datatable A
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a Dictionary object to classify and categorize your data/data-tables? That way you don't have to mess the UI with more things... The lookup on a dictionary is also very fast. Hope that helps :)

Edit: seems that I posted in about the same time with @sll

Comment: seems like I posted same time as you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a DataView.  It automatically indexes its columns.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a `DataSet` which is a group of tables (and relations between them).

You produce a table and then add it to the `DataSet` through `DataSet.Tables.Add()`

More information on `DataSet` is located here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx